# Windows 8.1 Installer goes to black screen after logo

Tags: windows-8, boot, drivers, display, chromebook

Well, as anyone that can see my previous questions knows, I am currently in the quest of putting windows 8.1 or 10 TP on my chromebook C710-2856.

I finally managed to create a bootable windows 8.1 installer USB using WinUSB for Debian.

I booted the installer on my chromebook, and the beta fish logo appears. Darn, I got the wrong .iso. The circles start spinning, and then the logo and fish disappear. The backlight remains on, and the computer appears to be running. However, I see nothing. I have tried hooking up a VGA cable from my chromebook to a monitor, which displays properly when I am running debian, but the monitor still shows nothing.

I fear that the installer cannot figure out how to use the display, and has faulty drivers.

I have heard of people installing windows on the C710-2856, and I am bewildered that it is not functioning properly. I flashed the coreboot BIOS on my chromebook meant for running windows, and yet this still happens.

Any ideas on how I can remedy this? I'm thinking I might be able to install in virtualbox under debian (my chromebook runs debian fine) and then install drivers that hopefully work from there.

NOTE: I have tried installing windows 10 TP, the same bizarre error occurs. I am making a win7 install USB right now, I will report back on the progress made there.

Comment: Can you get into Safe Mode? If not, then it isn't likely to be a video driver issue.

Comment: @AdamThompson is there a safe mode feature in the installer? How would i get to it? I don't already have win8.1 installed, I'm trying to install it. Nothing is showing up on the display after the beta fish logo and circles with the installer.

Comment: Ah - OK, I thought the installer had completed, and then you were getting a black screen (which is something I've seen before).